# Using a VueJS prop as a variable for array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to work out how I can use a variable (prop) as part of an array map function.

Basically I have this code:

```
var result = this.$store.getters['example/store'].map(a => a.fixed_column)
```

and I want `fixed_column` to be able to be a variable, allowing me to reuse this component in lots of places depending what column name is passed in as a prop.

I tried

```
.map(a => a.{this.category})
```

and other various syntax variations of that - but couldnt get it to work.

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
<my-component category="example_column"></my-component>
```

and have the array sum up `example_column`

This is my full vue component if needed:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Pending count: {{ pending }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
     export default {
         props: {
             category: {},
         }, 
         computed: {
             pending() {
                 var result = this.$store.getters['example/store'].map(a => a.fixed_column);
                 return result.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
             }
         },
     }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the type of `category` prop?

Comment: did you try `a[this.category]`?

Comment: @aBiscuit - I added some info to the question. Basically `category` would be a string I can set on the component to allow me to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to access object property dynamically would be via [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).
But for that to work, you have to make sure that `category` prop can be accessed inside the component. For that, valid prop declaration is required.

Here are essential parts for it to work:

```
props: {
  category: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default_category',
  }
},
computed: {
  pending() {
    const result = this.$store.getters['example/store'].map(a => a[this.category]);
    return result.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do it as follow  :

```
 var result = this.$store.getters['example/store'].map(a => a[this.category]);
```

and `category` should be a string